# Text formatting for strings in Google Documents from Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I have some Google Apps scripts that use the DocumentApp .replaceText method to find a text string in a Google Document and replace it with a different text string.

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
var newTextString = 'foo\nbar';
file.replaceText('Old text string',newTextString);
```

The \n works to make line breaks, but is there a way to format the text with bold/italics/colors/etc?

I tried to use HTML tags and inline CSS styles with the span tag, but that didn't work, it just outputs the text including the tags. I remember how Google Docs used to have an HTML button and you could see the markup that made up the content of the Google doc, but they took that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the functions describe at the API site [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text?hl=es#setItalic%28Boolean%29)

You can manipulate the text setting all styles as much as you want.
For example:

```
var file = DocsList.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
file.replaceText('Old text string',newTextString);
var newTextString = 'foo\nbar';

var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID_GOES_HERE');
var text = doc.editAsText();
text.setItalic(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, italic)
```

Comment: I think you mean DocumentApp.openById().  Also, replaceText is not on the Document object, but rather Paragraph, Body, HeaderSection, etc.

Comment: Changed the solution opening document by id with DocumentApp