# Why does Google Apps Script throw 'ReferenceError: "bold" is not defined' when using .setBold()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

**The context**: I need to process/correct many text documents containing multiple particular textual errors, highlight keywords in 'bold' and then output the result.  I have a Google spreadsheet with two worksheets: one with two columns of '*wrong wordforms*' and '*replacement wordforms*' (2d array) that I intend to add to over time and use it as a datastore to 'call from;' the other, a single-column collection of words (1d array) I designate "keywords" to check for and then highlight in the target documents.

**Things I've tried that worked**: I used a basic array iteration loop from a beginner video (I can't add more links yet, I apologize) and swapped in `body.replaceText()` for the `sendEmail()`, successfully, to process the corrections from my "datastore" into my target document, which works nearly perfectly.  It ignores text values without the exact same case...but that's a problem for another day.

```
function fixWords() {
// Document to edit
  var td = DocumentApp.openById('docId1');
// Document holding comparison datastore
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('docId2');
// Create data objects
  var body = td.getBody();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Word Replacements");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
// Create a loop (iterate through the cell data)
  for (i=1;i<values.length;i++) {
    fault = values[i][0];
    solution = values[i][2];
    body.replaceText(fault, solution);
  }
}
```

**Things I've tried that fail**: I then tried just swapping out values for `setBold()` with the `replaceText()` code, but the closest I got was the first instance of a keyword from the array would be styled correctly, but no further instances of it...unlike ALL of the instances of an incorrectly spelled word being corrected from the Word Replacements array using the fixWords function.

I found the '[highlightTextTwo' example here at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064972/can-i-color-certain-words-in-google-document-using-google-script/12072164#12072164) which works very well, but I couldn't figure out how to swap in an external data source or force the included different iteration loop to work in my favor.

I've scanned the GAS reference, watched [Google developer videos for snippets that might apply](http://youtu.be/KIiCSdRCqXc?t=23m36s)...but clearly I'm missing something that's probably basic to programming.  But I honestly don't know why this isn't as easy as the `body.replaceText()` functionality.

```
function boldKeywords() { // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064972
// Document to edit
  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById('docId1');
// Access the keyword worksheet, create objects
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('docId2');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Keywords");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var highlightStyle = {};
  highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = 'true';

  for (i=1; i<values.length; ++i) {
    textLocation = values[i];
    if (textLocation != null && textLocation.getStartOffset() != -1) {
      textLocation.getElement().setAttributes(textLocation.getStartOffset(),textLocation.getEndOffsetInclusive(), highlightStyle);
    }
  }
}
```

This throws out '*TypeError: Cannot find function getStartOffset in object DIV. (line 15, file "boldIt").*'  I guess this means that by just blindly swapping in this code, it's looking in the wrong object...but I cannot figure out why it works for `x.replaceText()` and not for `x.setAttributes()` or `x.setBold` or `.getElement().getText().editAsText()`...there just doesn't seem to be a "Learn Google Apps Script example" that deals with something this low on a scale of mundane, uninteresting use cases...enough for me to figure out how to direct it to the right object, and then manipulate the "if statement" parameters to get the behavior I need.

**My current brick wall**: I spotted this example, again, [Text formatting for strings in Google Documents from Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389284), and it seemed promising, even though the DocsList syntax has been deprecated (I'm fairly sure).  But now I get "bold is not defined" thrown at me.  Bold...is not defined.  *:: mouth agape ::*

```
function boldKeywords() {
// Access the keyword worksheet, create objects
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('docId1');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Keyterms");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

// Open target document for editing
  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById('docId2');
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // Loop function: find given keyword value from spreadsheet in target document
  // and then bold it (highlight with style 'bold')
  for (i=1; i<values.length; ++i) {
    keyword = values[i];
    target = body.findText(keyword);
    body.replaceText(target,keyword);
    text = body.editAsText();
    text.setBold(text.startOffset, text.endOffsetInclusive, bold);
  }
}
```

I will happily sacrifice my firstborn so that your crops may flourish for the coming year in exchange for some insight.

Answer (score 1):

I use this for my scripts, the setStyleAttribute method.

Documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ui_supportedStyles

Example :

```
TexBox.setStyleAttribute("fontWeight", "bold");
```

Comment: I see. This is strictly tied to the Ui Services?  So, if you are making an add-on or a web app? I figured if I was having so much trouble with just highlighting text in one document using an array from a different spreadsheet, I probably couldn't handle more complexity...like making my own user interface...but I will add this to my list of things to read up on. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `bold` parameter is a Boolean data type.  You need to use the word `true` or `false`.

Replace "bold" with "true".

```
text.setBold(text.startOffset, text.endOffsetInclusive, true);
```

Check out the "**Type**" column in the documentation:

[Google Documentation - setBold](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#setBold(Integer,Integer,Boolean))

Comment: This does answer the question as I posed it.  And that's what I get for taking the literal code from the example...  I might have to reconfigure my question, though...there's clearly something really wrong (i.e., other errors) with how I'm trying to accomplish what I need.  I'll revisit this tonight, after I sleep and tinker with it.  Also, I can't upvote your comment until I have a smidgen more rep...but as soon as I do, it's yours.